# Why CSS3 media query @media(max-width) is not working

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design, responsive

I am trying to apply some responsive design into the website. I do not understand why I have a problem when I apply the following media query. Thank you for your help.
**A part of HTML (index.html)**

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content ='ie-edge'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-xxzQGERXS00kBmZW/6qxqJPyxW3UR0BPsL4c8ILaIWXva5kFi7TxkIIaMiKtqV1Q" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel ='stylesheet' href='css/style.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-width: 768px)' href ='css/widescreen.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 1100px)' href ='css/mobile.css'>
```

**CSS part in which media query is not working. (mobile.css)**

```
/*Smartphones */
@media(max-width: 500px){
  #navbar {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `display:flex;` inside #navbar

```
@media(max-width: 500px){
  #navbar {
    display:flex; /*new*/
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

Comment: Also need a space between @media and the (features). More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#Targeting_media_features

Answer (score -1):

First, the styles of "mobile.css" file will never be applied because you specified in the meta tag the expression: `media='screen and (min-width: 1100px)'` which tells the browser to apply the styles for devices with a screen's width >= 1100px, so below that, the "mobile.css" styles will not be applied.

Second, in case of a screen width >= 1100px, the mobile styles will not be applied because you added another media query with different rule `@media(max-width: 500px)` which tells the browser to apply the style if the screen's width is below 500px, while we are in a screen's width >= 1100px, it will never work...

To resolve your problem, just keep one expression rule to apply the styles of mobile.css file for smaller screens' width ( <= 500px ) like:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-width: 500px)' href ='css/mobile.css'>
```

And then, remove the duplicated media query rule in "mobile.css":

```
#navbar {
   flex-direction: column;
   align-items: center;
   display: flex;
}
```

Useful links:

- [refer to this link for more informations about the use of media queries](http://you%20have%20to%20add%20the%20property%20%22display:%20flex%22%20in%20order%20to%20use%20the%20properties%20%22flex-direction%22%20and%20%22align-items%22,%20%5Brefer%20to%20this%20link%20for%20more%20details%20about%20flexbox%5D%5B1%5D)
- you have to add the property "display: flex" in order to use the properties "flex-direction" and "align-items", [refer to this link for more details about flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)